# jQuery mobile - on click grab id of element where attribue data-collapsed is false

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

hopefully someone can help me with this issue. 
I'm working with jQuery Mobile and I want to grab the id of an element on click, but only if the list item is not collapsed. Below is what I have.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="myPage">
  <h3>Current Clients</h3>
  <div data-role="collapsible-set">

    <div data-role='collapsible' data-collapsed='true' class='userList'>
      <h3 id='1' class='unverified getID'>John Doe</h3>
      <div>
        <p>collapsed content 1</p>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- .userList -->

    <div data-role='collapsible' data-collapsed='true' class='userList'>
      <h3 id='2' class='verified getID'>Jane Doe</h3>
      <div>
        <p>collapsed content 2</p>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- .userList -->

  </div><!-- collapsible-set -->
</div><!-- #myPage -->
```

JS:

```
var thisID;
$(".getID").click(function(e) {
  if($(this).parent(".userList").attr('data-collapsed', false)){
    thisID = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(thisID);
  }  
});
```

Here is the above code in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8xHmj/9/

It gets the id but alerts every time element is clicked, collapsed or not. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement is actually setting the attribute, change it to this:

```
if ($(this).parent(".userList").attr('data-collapsed') == 'false')
```

You can also check by using the `.data` function:

```
if ($(this).parent(".userList").data('collapsed') == 'false')
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. It didn't fix the issue completely but it fixed the major issue I was having and question I asked. Thanks again